# How to add new ssh keys to an existing droplet?

Tags: macos, ssh, digital-ocean, droplet

I have an existing droplet that I can connect to from my ubuntu machine via ssh. I would like to also be able to connect to it from my mac via ssh. I added a new ssh key to my account [here](https://cloud.digitalocean.com/account/security), but when I try to connect from my mac I get:

`root@<ip_of_droplet>: Permission denied (publickey)`

I know I added my ssh keys correctly to my droplet and they are stored in the default location on my mac. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

In your mac, you should have an ssh public key located at `~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub`. Copy the contents of that file, and add it to the end of `/root/.ssh/authorized_keys` in your droplet. Make sure it's on its own line.